# Why is Excel warning about user-defined function conflicts with ISFORMULA?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Every time I open a particular .XLSB in Office 365 (Excel 2016) I get the following warning.  I did a case-insensitive search of the entire workbook formulas for "isformula" and came up empty.  I checked the VBA editor and find *nothing* defined there.  I checked Conditional Formatting rules and again came 
up with *nothing*.  Nothing in the Name Manager names, values, or references contains that text.  What else could be prompting this warning?

[image: Excel Warning]

Comment: Were I in your shoes, one place I would check would be the Name Manager, though I'm not sure you'd find anything there. It's also possible the user-defined function you're looking for is hidden.

Comment: @BillDOe: Yes, also checked the Name Manager....